# SQL return last column value which isn't null in a set of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, coalesce

In SQL we use COALESCE to return the first value that isn't null. But how can we get the last value that isn't null in a set of columns.

eg:

```
COLA    COLB    COLC    COLD
Asi     Bhs     Null    Null
```

**Expected output**

Bhs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it in reverse:

```
coalesce(cold, colc, colb, cola)
```

Comment: Why didn't I know this! ugh